# How to create log file using log4j in struts2+hibernate application?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using Struts2,hibernate web application. On that file i used following dependency for log4j in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.9</version>
 </dependency>
```

In my Actionclass i used the following code to write log file:

```
 public class loginAction extends action{
     static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(com.action.LoginAction.class);

     public String checklogin(){
          log.debug("Debug Message(LOGIN)!");
      log.info("Info Message(LOGIN)!");
      log.warn("Warn Message(LOGIN)!");
      log.error("Error Message(LOGIN)!");
      log.fatal("Fatal Message(LOGIN)!");

           //my coding for checking logged status.
     } 
 }
```

I have placed log4j.properties file under WEB-INF/classes folder with the following code,

```
 log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.file.File=C\:\\logfile.log
 log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
 log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n 

  # Root logger option
  log4j.rootLogger=debug, file
```

When i run and deploy this application on server the property file is placed in correct path. but after running statement in action class nothing get affect from log4j.properties file. I dont know where i did wrong.

So anyone please help me to find this issue. Thanks in Advance.